# How to enable seeking in Azure Blob stream

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, streamwriter, seek

I have a BlobStream that is created from the method OpenWriter.

```
var blob = CloudContainer.GetBlobReference(name));
if (blob == null)
{
   return null;
}

return blob.OpenWrite();
```

Using this stream i would like to seek or set the position, but each time i do this i get a NotSupportedException. After doing some research i found that the canSeek is set to false, which causes this problem. But, the CanSeek is false only if the length is unknown. But the length is known when i run the debugger.

Why is CanSeek false?
How can i make it set to true?

Comment: What version of the client library are you using? What type is the underlying blob (Block or Page)? In the latest v2.0 client it looks like you can only Seek a write stream on Page blobs, so it may just not be possible.

Comment: i am using a block blob.

Comment: are there any big differences between the block and the page ?

Comment: I have quickly changed to page to see if it works. Ill keep you posted.

Comment: OpenWrite method is not supported by pageblobs.

Comment: I haven't worked a lot with Page blobs, but clearly you can write to Page blobs, otherwise how would you create one? The [BlobWriteStreamBase](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/microsoft-azure-api/Services/Storage/Lib/Common/Blob/BlobWriteStreamBase.cs) class has explicit support for writing and seeking page blobs. It would be helpful if you said which client library version you're using, and posted the code you're using to create the blob.

Comment: I found that seeking in a page blob was possible. But it is extra work to write in batches of 512 bytes. What i did was to create a stream from the blob and copy it to a memorystream for manipulation. It is not really recommended, since doing alot of reading and writing against the blob is slow if you need an application with focus on performance. But your answer @BrianReischl is a good answer. If you write something for an answer i will mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can seek within a page blob - there is explicit support for it in [BlobWriteStreamBase](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Blob/BlobWriteStreamBase.cs) class.

I think you could also read & write to specified parts of a Block blob using HTTP `Range` headers, which would be effectively the same thing as seeking. But I think you'd have to implement that yourself.

Comment: There are limitations to seeking with page blob. Correct me if im wrong, but i think you can only read and write 512 bytes at a time. This means that the seeking must be done to each position increment of 512. (512*x, where x is a whole number)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of returning from `blobclient.OpenRead`, you can return a wrapped stream using below code. Our requirement is to enable parallel and resumable Azure blob downloads from loadbalanced fileservers. There might be some issues in code, please review it and fix them as required.

When returning `controller.File(stream, contentType, filename, true)` in controller, since last parameter `enableRangeProcessing=true`, it verifies `stream.CanSeek=true` and calls `stream.Seek` with incoming contentrangeheader's `range.from` value.

So wrap the source with `return new SeekableBlobReadStream(blobclient)` and send it to controller.

```
internal class SeekableBlobReadStream : Stream
{
    private Stream stream;
    private readonly BlobBaseClient client;
    private readonly BlobProperties properties;

    public SeekableBlobReadStream(BlobBaseClient client)
    {
        properties = client.GetProperties().Value;
        this.client = client;
    }

    private void PrepareStream(long position = 0)
    {
        if (stream == null || position != 0)
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Dispose();
            stream = client.OpenRead(new BlobOpenReadOptions(false) { Position = position });
        }
    }

    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanSeek => true;

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override long Length => properties.ContentLength;

    public override long Position
    {
        get => (stream?.Position).GetValueOrDefault();
        set => PrepareStream(value);
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        PrepareStream();
        stream.Flush();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        PrepareStream();
        return stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        switch (origin)
        {
            case SeekOrigin.Current:
                offset = Position + offset;
                break;
            case SeekOrigin.End:
                offset = Length - offset;
                break;
        }
        PrepareStream(offset);
        return stream.Position;
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you for sharing it.