# Do Azure Blob Stroage Blobs support random-accessible streams?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to random-access Azure Blob Storage Blobs from .NET?
(i.e., is the returned stream.CanSeek == true and stream.Seek() works without buffering the whole file in memory)

I cannot try it + I've searched the MSDN and used Google but I cannot find an answer. Hope somebody here knows it.

(optimally the answer is a link to the MSDN...)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to read just a portion of the blob. For example, if you have a 1 GB blob, you want to read say 1 MB of the data from that blob without reading entire 1 GB data first in memory.

If that's the case, then you can make use of [`DownloadRangeToStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadrangetostream?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) or [`DownloadRangeToStreamAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadrangetostreamasync?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) method. In both the methods, you can specify an offset (i.e. starting point) and the length of data you would want to read from that offset.

Comment: No, I want to have a random-acess stream where I can freely seek to any position. Actually, I have another library which works based upon a random-access stream. CanSeek must return true and the library must have the option to call Seek() - of course with a minimal overhead + without having to preload the whole blob into memory (my blobs are huge).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497241/how-to-enable-seeking-in-azure-blob-stream/16590011#16590011):

> You can seek within a page blob - there is explicit support for it in
>   [BlobWriteStreamBase](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Blob/BlobWriteStreamBase.cs)
>   class.
>
> I think you could also read & write to specified parts of a Block blob
>   using HTTP `Range` headers, which would be effectively the same thing
>   as seeking. But I think you'd have to implement that yourself.

In short, what you need to do is implement an adapter: your own stream, which calls a method like [DownloadRangeToStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadrangetostream?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) under the hood, but acts like it's a stream itself.

Comment: We could write such an adapter, however, are you sure about your documentation reference. You are talking about Blob*Write*StreamBase, shouldn't it be something along Blob*Read*StreamBase?

Comment: You're right, the answer I referred to was about write streams. However, the same thing applies. I'm not sure why the blom streams don't support seeking by default, but if you need that specific functionality, I rolling your own is your best bet.